# Kotlin. How to store property in value class?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, value-class, backing-field, kotlin-inline-class

I'm trying to create value class for storing money. And I need to store private money format. Here is my code:

```
@JvmInline
value class Money internal constructor(val rawValue: String) {

    private val format: MoneyFormat = MoneyFormat.WHOLE
```

And I retrieve error:

> Value class cannot have properties with backing fields

But on the other hand, if you look at the implementation of kotlin.time.Duration you can find the property `storageUnit` there. And as far as I understand, it is necessary to store the current duration unit.

How can I save the format in my class so that I can add methods that can transfer money from one format to another?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of inline/value classes is that internally we don't instantiate an object of the class, but we use its single value directly (at least where it is possible). In your case that means we don't want to pass `Money` object, but a string directly. We can't store this additional `format` value in the string object, so we can't add such property.

`Duration.storageUnit` is different:

```kotlin
private val storageUnit get() = if (isInNanos()) DurationUnit.NANOSECONDS else DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS
```

It doesn't store any additional data in the object. Whenever we access `storageUnit` property, it calculates the needed value dynamically and returns it. It doesn't store it anywhere.

Looking at your example, I suppose you wanted to do the same:

```kotlin
private val format: MoneyFormat get() = MoneyFormat.WHOLE
```

Please note `get()`. This is different than your original code. Your code creates a field and stores `MoneyFormat.WHOLE` when instantiating the object. After adding `get()` no field is created, only the getter and the getter returns `MoneyFormat.WHOLE`.